# AWS VPC Peering with private instances of other VPC under auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, private-subnet, aws-vpc-peering

I have successfully created a VPC peering connection between two private instances if I know their private IP addresses. However, I want to achieve a VPC peering for private instances under the auto-scaling group. Please have a look at the following diagram to understand the infrastructure layout.

[image]

One of my applications is deployed over a private instance, in VPC B which needs a connection to another application deployed in private instances of VPC A. All the instances are highly scalable due to the Load Balancer and Scaling group.

One way to achieve this connection is a NAT gateway installed in the public subnet of VPC B to request out to the Internet and received by VPC A and routed towards the load balancer. This is a long round trip, and it has more cost. So I want to achieve it by other means like VPC peering but How can I determine the private IP for instances under VPC A at run time?

Or can we use VPC peering to do a connection towards the Loadbalancer of VPC A which can route to any private instance?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Current Configuration:
Here is how currently traffic discovers VPC A.

When I call https://www.domainForVPCAPrivateInstance.com/api/healthCheck
from any private instance under VPC B, Here is the route It take.

VPC-B: private ec2 -> NAT gateway => internet -> DNS translation -> VPC A: Elastic load blanacer -> to any private instance in VPC A

See Here traffic went through the internet. But VPC peering allows us to communicate between two VPC privately. But for that I have to know the private IP of any instance in VPC A. e.g.

https://private-ip-of-ec2-under-vpc-A/api/healthCheck

Right?  But I can't determine. IP of instances when they are under load balancer and auto scaling group.  They are highly scalable. So which solution allows to communicate between two VPCs' private instances privately when they are under auto scaling?

Comment: A VPC peering connection is a networking connection between **two VPCs** that enables you to route traffic between them using private IPv4 addresses or IPv6 addresses. (From ```https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html```). You can see scenarios and configurations on that page.

Comment: @Franxi , Yes I know that its between private ipv4. How can I determine the private Ipv4 address of private instances running under the load balancer and auto scaling group? that was my actual question.

Comment: Why you have to determine the private IPv4 address of private instances running under the load balancer? Peering between 2 VPCs, so the traffic can be routed to LB or EC2 ... Of course, you need to update the route table.

Comment: "I want to achieve it" I don't understand what you  are trying to achieve.  what are you asking to do, specifically?

Comment: I think you are asking [How can I access an internal load balancer using VPC peering?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elb-access-load-balancer-vpc-peering)

Comment: @FranxiHidro the load balancer is public, you can't use it for internal network communication. They are asking about directly accessing the instances without using the load balancer.

Comment: Access all the ec2 instances is not a good option in a highly scalable environment.

Comment: @FranxiHidro I have edited my question. Please check Edit to make my question more clear.

Comment: @jarmod Yes I am looking for something similar, I will give it a try. Can I use the existing public load balancer with this approach? or I must create an internal load balancer.

Comment: @FranxiHidro Both VPC route tables had already been updated , Security groups allow traffic of http, when I successfully communicated using VPC peering and private IPv4 address of ec2 from VPC-A, I have a destination to VPC-A CIDR and target to peering connection. in both side of route tables. However when instances are under auto scalling group and ALB then instances keep changing due to scale out and scale in.

Comment: @Mubasher Accessing the instances directly is not a good solution in your case. You already know that. I think you can consider using NAT GW or internal ALB + VPC peering. Maybe you need to compare pricing, scalability, security, operation effort...

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [AWS Cloud Map](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud-map/).

Or you could have your code running in VPC B do some sort of lookup using the AWS API, via an AWS SDK, to get the list of instances registered with the load balancer.

Or you could add an Internal load balancer that points to the same targets, and make your requests to that.

Comment: Can we use private endpoint? I don't have account to test it.

Comment: @FranxiHidro do you mean AWS Private Link? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/concepts.html Yes you could use that, but it still requires you to create another load balancer.

Comment: I mean the VPC endpoint, powered by AWS PrivateLink. I know it can work for the internal ALB, but I'm not sure about the internet-facing ALB.

Comment: @FranxiHidro You can't use AWS PrivateLink with an ALB at all, you have to have an NLB.

Comment: @MarkB I will evaluate all three solutions and will check which one works and is more feasible in terms of scalability and cost.

Comment: @MarkB You are right, PrivateLink only supports NLB.